# How can we set reminder/alarm to the calendar-android full source code?

Tags: android

I'm learning android currently, I have tried a lot to put reminder in calendar. But many errors are coming, so how can I set an android reminder in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Learn Android");
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Home suit home");
intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Download Examples");
```

The above snippet shows how to add an event to the calendar. The following shows how to set the start and end time of the reminder:

```
// Setting dates
GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 10, 02);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

Source: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCalendar/article.html#calendarapi